# wp_upload_bits does not retrieve images that do not have an extension

Tags: images, errors, customization

I am using the following code to retrieve images from the web:

```
$get = wp_remote_get($image_file_name);
$mirror = wp_upload_bits(basename($image_file_name), '', wp_remote_retrieve_body($get));
```

This code works just fine with all sorts of images except when images have no extension. For example, if image file name was:

```
http://www.some_site.com/image_filename.jpg
```

then running the above code would be ok. However, the link

```
http://www.some_site.com/another_image_filename_but_without_extension
```

would give the following error:

```
Array
(
    [error] => Invalid file type
)
```

After further investigation, it looks like wp_upload_bits has the following code in it:

```
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $name );
if ( ! $wp_filetype['ext'] && ! current_user_can( 'unfiltered_upload' ) )
    return array( 'error' => __( 'Invalid file type' ) );
```

And it seems that it is checking if an extension actually exists, and if not, then there is an error.

So my question is how do I work around this to download images that do not have extensions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the URL of an extension-less image to test this but I'd think that the server would have to pass a `content-type` header. If that is the case, you should be able to look at `$get['headers']['content-type']`, find out what kind of image it is, and tack the appropriate extension onto `$image_file_name` before sending it to `wp_upload_bits`.

You've already retrieved the information. Take a look at `var_dump($get)`, so the idea is to do something like this:

```
$get = wp_remote_get($image_file_name);
$ending = file_ending_parsing_function($get['headers']['content-type']);
$mirror = wp_upload_bits(basename($image_file_name.$ending), '', wp_remote_retrieve_body($get));
```

[`wp_remote_retrieve_body`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_retrieve_body) just grabs information already present in `$get`, retrieved by `wp_remote_get`, so you aren't faced with downloading a file that doesn't exist and I ran a test to confirm that the first parameter of [`wp_upload_bits`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_bits) can be anything you choose so long as the extensions match. In fact, tentative testing suggests that it just needs to *have* an extension. I was able to upload a `.jpg` and rename it to a `.gif` extension without manipulating the file at all.

Comment: I am using the following code `$type = wp_remote_retrieve_header( $get, 'content-type' );` to get the image type. Now let's assume that it was a jpg image, then the url for the image would be `http://www.some_site.com/another_image_filename_but_without_extension.jpg` which actually does not exist! Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Greeso : see the edit